# Calling fopen gives malloc error at runtime

Tags: c, string, file, malloc

I'm reading a file's contents into a string with this function

```
void readFile2String(char **string, char location[]){
    FILE *fileList;
    int size;
    char *temp;
    char command[1024];


    if((fileList=fopen(location,"r")) == NULL){
        perror(" Error opening list of directories: ");
        exit(2);
    }

    fseek(fileList,0,SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fileList);
    rewind(fileList);
    temp = malloc((size+1)*(sizeof(char)));
    fread(temp,sizeof(char),size,fileList);
    temp[size]=0;   // Terminate string with 0
    *string = temp;
    fclose(fileList);
}
```

and I'm using the string for further manipulation. I'm calling this function as

```
char *temp;
readFile2String(&temp, fileName);
```

I successfully get the file contents in the string. But when at a later point I try to use fopen again, I get malloc error at runtime. I've tried commenting out the call to this function in this program and after that, I have been able to use fopen as many times as I want. What is wrong with my function?

Thanks.

Comment: everything you `malloc` must be given back with `free`. You're basically leaking memory. Maybe not right away, but somewhere later on.

Comment: You didn't include the exact error that you're getting so it is difficult to suggest a reason why it doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: ftell() returns a `long` not an `int`, so size's declaration should be `long size;`... this could be a big issue for a very large file.

Comment: Note: `sizeof(char)` will never yield anything different than `1`. No need to take it. If you want to make the `malloc` more portable (for whatever reason), use `sizeof(*temp)`.

Comment: `ftell` returns a `long int`. That might be the same width as `int`, but you should not rely in it.

Comment: by the way, you don't check the returned value from malloc.  You can even reach the case where the `size` value doesn't allow you to **malloc()**

Answer (score 1):

1. "fopen()" isn't causing the memory corruption'  Neither is failing to "free()" (if in fact you're not doing a free().
2. You're validating the return from "fopen()" - good.  Q: Why aren't you also checking fseek(), ftell(), rewind() and fread() for error conditions?
3. My guess is `temp[size]=0;` might be the culprit that actually causes the memory corruption.  Or perhaps `fread()`.  Knowing "size" would definitely be useful.

SUGGESTION:

Carefully walk through the debugger, and validate your I/O returns each step of the way